# meaning of 'narrow' in 'narrow possessiveness'

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

What does 'narrow' mean in the following sentence, which is from *Political Ideals* (1917) by Bertrand Russell?

> He will not desire for his country the passing triumphs of a **narrow** possessiveness, but rather the enduring triumph of having helped to embody in human affairs something of that spirit of brotherhood which Christ taught and which the Christian churches have forgotten.

Does it mean *selfish*?

Comment: ...possibly along the lines of  [limited to a small area of  interest, activity, or thought](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/narrow)

Comment: Hmmnn... _selfish_ is probably the best description...before that, Russell uses comparisons like "magnanimous, just, and generous." among many, many other positive attributes, mostly indicating _selflessness_. I like this question; however I am thinking it might get closed for POB. ....IMO, it should be seen as a discrete unit; i.e. "narrow possessiveness"